# Add or change a value of JSON key with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have a `JSON` `string(?)` that I have returned from `$.ajax()` and named it `data`. Some of the values are empty and I need to add values to some of the keys and send it back to my PHP script.

I access the existing values by `data.keyName`. How do I add or change the values of certain keys in `data`?

This is what `data` looks like.

```
{
    "ID":"48",
    "userID":"0",
    "address":"750 North High Street",
    "city":"Columbus",
    "state":"OH",
    "zip":"43215",
    "lat":"39.977673",
    "lng":"-83.003357",
    "busNumber":"55",
    "isClaimed":"N",
    "whereFound":"",
    "busNum":"",
    "email":"",
    "fname":"",
    "lname":"",
    "comments":""
}
```

Comment: If you access the values with `data.keyName`, you no longer have a *JSON string*. You have a *JavaScript object*. JSON has already been parsed into an object for you.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, Ates. I was confused about that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Once you have decoded the JSON, the result is a JavaScript object.  Just manipulate it as you would any other object.  For example:

```
data.busNum = 12345;
...
```

Comment: Why didn't I try that... Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

```
var temp = data.oldKey; // or data['oldKey']
data.newKey = temp;
delete data.oldKey;
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems if your key is saved in a variable. `data.key = value` won't work.

You should use `data[key] = value`

Example:

```
data = {key1:'v1', key2:'v2'};

var mykey = 'key1'; 
data.mykey = 'newv1';
data[mykey] = 'newV2';

console.log(data);
```

Result:

```
{
  "key1": "newV2",
  "key2": "v2",
  "mykey": "newv1"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just like you would for any other variable, you just set it

```
alert(data.ID);
data.ID = "bar";  //dot notation 
alert(data.ID);    
data.userID = 123456;
data["address"] = "123 some street"; //bracket notation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.userID = "10";
```

Comment: If userID exists as a key, this answer duplicates it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var y_axis_name=[];

 for(var point in jsonData[0].data)
              { 
                y_axis_name.push(point);

              }
```

y_axis_name is having all the key name

try on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gajender/wL7u9hsz/)

Answer (score 0):

You just set the data value like a normal javascript variable
Ex:

```
data["userID"] = 4; // or data.userID = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//We loop inside the array with "for"
for(let i = 0; i < _arrayJsonItems.length; i++)
{
    //First, we write the keys we want to delete
    delete _arrayJsonItems[i].KeyOne;
    delete _arrayJsonItems[i].KeyTwo;

    //Finally, we add new values ​​with the same key names.
    _arrayJsonItems[i].KeyOne = "NewValue";
    _arrayJsonItems[i].KeyTwo = "NewValue";
    
}
```

Comment: could use forEach:  _arrayJsonItems.forEach((item) => { })