# JSONObject how to change value depend on key value?

Tags: javascript, json

I've a json like this :

```
[
    {
        "pages": "foo1",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo2",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo3",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo4",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo5",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo6",
        "hasil": ""
    }
]
```

so I want to change value of `hasil` key depending on `pages` value,
how can I do that?

EDIT for clear asking

I want to change value of specific json key like this :

```
[
    {
        "pages": "foo1",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo2",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo3",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo4",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo5",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo6",
        "hasil": "1"
    }
]
```

research : [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp), [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430193/add-or-change-a-value-of-json-key-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Which value you want to add?

Comment: What do you mean "dependent" ? something like if (arr[0].pages === 'foo1') {arr[0].hasil = 'bar';} ?

Comment: Find the object matching `pages` using `.forEach(`, `for-loop`, `.filter(`, and then assign a value to `hasil`.

Comment: Try using a `for` loop. You can access to each object of the array, check the `pages` value and then set the `hasil` value,

Comment: That does not look like research !

Comment: i mean `change` , wrong word sentences,

Comment: @flix, check my answer

Comment: @AkashAgrawal your answer looks great, but i cant accepted answer for now, need 5 more minutes, btw can u help me the keyword of my json? its looks like not a nested jsonObject,

Comment: @flix Try this neat and clean - data.find((item) => item.pages === 'foo6').hasil = "hello"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fas as I understand your problem statment, are you looking for something like this?

```js
var data = [
    {
        "pages": "foo1",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo2",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo3",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo4",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo5",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo6",
        "hasil": ""
    }
];

for(let key in this.data){
  if(this.data[key].pages == 'foo1'){
    this.data[key].hasil = 'hello';
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find`;

```js
var array = [
    {
        "pages": "foo1",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo2",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo3",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo4",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo5",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo6",
        "hasil": ""
    }
];

var foundItem = array.find(function(element) {
  return element.pages == "foo5";
});
foundItem.hasil = "123";
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over the json objects and apply hasil according to your requirements:

```
var data = [
    {
        "pages": "foo1",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo2",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo3",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo4",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo5",
        "hasil": ""
    },
    {
        "pages": "foo6",
        "hasil": ""
    }
];

for(let obj of data){
  let pages = obj['pages'];
  if (pages.includes('foo')) {
    obj['hasil'] = "h" + pages;
  }
}

console.log(data);
```