# How to change value of JSON using for loop/ foreach?

Tags: javascript

I've tried to change the value of json depending on key, but my loop not work

here's the code:

```js
var duce2 = [{
    "pages": "foo1",
    "hasil": ""
  },
  {
    "pages": "foo2",
    "hasil": ""
  },
  {
    "pages": "foo3",
    "hasil": ""
  },
  {
    "pages": "foo4",
    "hasil": ""
  },
  {
    "pages": "foo5",
    "hasil": ""
  },
  {
    "pages": "foo6",
    "hasil": ""
  }
];

for (let key in this.duce2) {
  console.log("jalan ga fornya");
  if (this.duce2[key].pages == 'foo2') {
    console.log("jalan ga ifnya");
    this.duce2[key].hasil = '1';
  }
}
console.log(duce2);
```

did i doing something wrong with the code above? the console.log doesn't appear on `for` and `if`

EDIT : my chrome dev console just showing this

[image]

Comment: Where is the Json string?

Comment: @Nope I just copied the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48259530/8943429), the code looks fine in snippet

Comment: I run your code and console.logs were shown. There is `hasil: '1'` in the second object which i think was what you intended?

Comment: Seems to be working

Comment: or maybe the jquery 1.12.4 doesn't support this code?

Comment: You are very confusing. Where does jQuery all of a sudden come from, there is no jQuery in your code? - `the console.log doesn't appear on for and if` - It seems that it does display fine when running the snippet, if it doesn't in your implementation you need to post the code you are using instead.

Comment: @Nope sure i'm confusing, when I add `duce2 = ("[" + linkawal + "]");` above `for` line and change `var duce2` to `var linkawal`, the console showing [this](https://pasteboard.co/H31EX4m.png)

Comment: That creates a string, not an array, you can't use `$.each` on a string.

Comment: `this.duce2` should just be `duce2`.

Comment: @Barmar `this.duce2 should just be duce2` is the answer, thanks for help sir +1

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you use "this.duce2" in your code.
However, some useful advices :

- variables should be declared using the least permissive scope. Instead of declaring the array with "var", you should prefer "const"
- arrays should not be traversed using the for...in construction (which is for object properties). Instead, you should prefer to use the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

The result would be:

```
const duce2 = [ ... ];
duce2.forEach((elem) => {
  if (elem.pages === 'foo2') {
    elem.hasil = '1';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use duce2 instead of this.duce2,

You can iterate like this.

```
   for (var key in duce2) {
    if (duce2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if(duce2[key].pages=='foo2'){
    //your code ,what needs to be done.

    }
    }
    }
```

The for/in statement loops through the properties of an object.
Hope it helps..!