# javascript Json : change attribute value in a json structure

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, typescript

I am trying to change a specific key's value in json as below :

```
input = [{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"attritionManaged"},{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"attritionUnManaged"},{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"EHC"}]

output= [{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"managedAttrition"},{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"unmanagedAttrition"},{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"EndingHeadcount"}]
```

i have tried looping in the input like `input.forEach(element =>{//code})`but somewhere iam missing.

Comment: This is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430193/add-or-change-a-value-of-json-key-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add or change a value of JSON key with jquery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430193/add-or-change-a-value-of-json-key-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: If you are changing a value, you aren't working with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This not works??

```
let input = [{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"attritionManaged"},{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"attritionUnManaged"},{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"EHC"}]

 input.forEach(i=>{
     i.metric = 'abc'
 })

 input.forEach(i=>{
     alert(i.metric) 
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used spread operator: 
Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

example:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = [4,5,6]
a.push(...b)
a //which is [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

```js
input = [{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"attritionManaged"},{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"attritionUnManaged"},{"201708":10,"201709": 12, "metric":"EHC"}]
 
var output = input;
output.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr){
 currentValue.metric = getString(currentValue.metric);
})

function getString(str){
 var arr = [];
 var arr1 = [];
 var isUpperArrived = 0;
 if(str.length>0)
 {
  arr.push(str[0].toUpperCase());
 }
 
 for(var i=1;i<str.length;i++)
 {
  if(str[i]==str[i].toUpperCase())
  {
   isUpperArrived=1;
   arr1.push(str[i].toLowerCase());
  }else{
   if(!isUpperArrived)
   {
     arr.push(str[i]);
   }else{
    arr1.push(str[i]);
   }
  }
  
 }
 //pushing arr using spread operator
 arr1.push(...arr);
 return arr1.join('');
}


console.log(output);
```